# Wait until CCMoveTo is done?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making a BlackJack game using cocos2d and there is a problem that I can't seem to find a solution to. I'm trying to make the initial deal screen like this:

- First card sprite will move from off screen to player's hand
- Second card sprite will move from off screen to dealer's hand
- Third -> player
- Fourth -> dealer

To do this I call the method drawCard from both Player and Dealer classes:

```
[self.player drawCard];
[self.dealer drawCard];
[self.player drawCard];
[self.dealer drawCard];
```

In the drawCard method:

```
-(void) drawCard {
.......
id move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4 position:ccp(x, y)];
        [card.sprite runAction:move];
......
}
```

I want the first card to finish moving to the designated position before the second card starts moving, but in reality all 4 cards start moving at almost the same time. Please help me resolve this problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in 2ways 1. Use `CCDelayTime` 2. Use `CCCallBlock`

**1. Using `CCdelayTime`**

```
   [self.player drawCard:0]; 
   [self.dealer drawCard:0.5f]; 
   [self.player drawCard:1.0f]; 
   [self.dealer drawCard:1.5f];

    -(void) drawCard:(float)delay
    {
       if(!delay)
       {
          id move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4 position:ccp(x, y)];
          [card.sprite runAction:move];
       }
       else
       {
          id delay    = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:delay];
          id move     = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4 position:ccp(x, y)];
          id sequence = [CCSequence actions:delay, move, nil];
          [card.sprite runAction:sequence];
       }

    }
```

**2. Using `CCCallBlock`**

```
    -(void) drawCard:(id)inCard
    {
        mCardIndex++; //in init mCardIndex=0

        id move    = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4 position:ccp(x, y)];
        id calBlk  = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{

                            if(mCardIndex <= TOTAL_CARD)
                            {
                                //here get rightCard
                                [self drawCard:newCard];
                            }
                    }];
        id sequence = [CCSequence actions: move, calBlk,  nil];

        [inCard.sprite runAction:sequence];    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked! One question though: I thought an action needs to finish before the next line is executed? And is there a more elegant way to achieve this same result? (I'm thinking multithreaded/ performselector:afterDelay or waitUntilDone)

Comment: updated my answer...instead of performselector its better to use CCCallBlock in cocos2d.